# what actually sets the _WIN32 or _WIN64 preprocessor?

Tags: c++, target, preprocessor

what actually sets the _WIN32 or _WIN64 preprocessor definition in most of sources
All sources I found out are that there isn't any

```
#define _WIN32
```

nor

```
#define _WIN64
```

but as the source is compiled by GCC the preprocessor get into true condition as if definition has been written and defined,

also question apply too to other OS keywords as it most likely has such the same behavior
Thanks much.

Answer (score 6):

As can be read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019):

> `_WIN64` Defined as 1 when the compilation target is 64-bit ARM or
>   x64. Otherwise, undefined.

There isn't an actual `#define` anywhere. The compiler just adds it to its known definitions based on its compilation target. This all happens in the compiler itself, not in any translation unit(/C++ file).

Answer (score 1):

The standard specifies nine phases of translation of every source file.  A compiler is required to produce the same result as if it has executed those nine phases in order.

The third phase handles parsing of input to produce preprocessing tokens, and the fourth phase involves execution of the preprocessor.  After execution of the preprocessor, there are no preprocessor directives waiting to be processed by later phases of compilation.

Logically, then, the introduction of compiler-defined macros like `_WIN32` and `_WIN64` will happen in either the third phase (relevant preprocessor tokens are generated, and then handled by the preprocessor) or in the preprocessor itself (initialisation of the preprocessor sets up data structures, so the macros are magically defined).

As to how *particular* compilers do it, you would have to examine the source code of the compilers.